# Bromination with NBS on cyclic structures

Tags: organic-chemistry, radicals, halogenation

> [image: azulene bromination]

I found this question and the answer as shown in my book. I didn't understand why the bromine particularly entered the position shown in the answer.

First of all, if a free radical was generated there it would be 2°, and also will have resonance. Is any other product possible or this is the only major product?

Also, is this allylic bromination? Every allylic position is also a vinylic position — I am not getting it.

Comment: Are you sure that this a radical bromination? :)

Comment: I have a question on that too , I really confused , like there is no allylic position and every allylic position is like a vinylic position. I am not getting this

Comment: This is aromatic azulene and it's simple reaction with Br2

Comment: Usually, these types of problems can be explained by looking at the intermediate that has resonance structures that don't disrupt the aromaticity of the other ring to where you've attacked.

Comment: Can anyone tell me where to learn how to write chemical formulas and reaction is stack exchange ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a follow-up to the excellent comments provided thus far, the following thoughts are added. Electrostatic Potential Map of azulene (**1a**) shows that there is high electron density in the 5-membered ring (red color signifies high electron density). The 5-membered ring is reminiscent of the aromaticity of cyclopentadienide anion and the 7-membered ring bears a positive charge and has aromaticity similar to cycloheptatrienyl cation. This phenomenon is represented in structure **1b**. The reaction does not involve bromine atom (a radical) because a bromine atom would be expected to attack the electropositive ring, not the electron-rich ring. The reaction is ionic and likely involves bromine rather than N-bromosuccinimide (NBS, **4**) directly. Bromine is liberated from NBS by trace amounts of HBr formed by the slow decomposition of NBS. In the event, bromination of azulene (**1c**) produces a resonance stabilized cation **2a**. Its canonical structure is **2b** that is identical to **2b'**. Loss of a proton from **2b** (or **2b'**) provides bromoazulene **3**.
[image]